# Backbone#Save model with POST

Tags: backbone.js, model

I have a Backbone model which can contain a lot of text data, this needs to be sent back to the server to update the row in the database.

This works great however, because the model can contain a lot of data, the URL will most likely be too long to send as a `PUT` request.

Instead, I need to somehow override the `Backbone#save` function to send the data as a `POST` request without modifying the URL parameter.

Ideally this only needs to be applied to one model.

Comment: Why would the data be too large for PUT but not for POST?

Comment: Does `PUT` not transfer the data directly in the URL too then?

Comment: No, it sends data just like POST.

Answer (score 1):

you can override Model.sync of given model, something like below

```
var oldSync = Backbone.Model.prototype.sync;

var MyModel  = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot:'someurl',
    sync:function(method, model){
        var args = _.toArray(arguments);
        console.log(args);
        if(method === 'update'){

            args[0]='create';
        }
        oldSync.apply(this, args);
    }
})


var model = new MyModel({id:'json'})
model.save();
```

Comment: I tried updating to the latest version, but it seems some of my code isn't working anymore, and unfortunately I don't have the time available to fix it all.

Comment: @James which version you are using now?

Comment: We're using `0.9.10` currently.

Answer (score 1):

3 options popping up in mind.

1.This should work.

```
model.save(null, {type: "POST"});
```

2.Another hack would be, that too if you are not considering about `id`.

```
model.id = null;
model.save();
```

3.Else, override like this.

```
var TextModel  = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync:function(){
        if (arguments[0] === "update" || arguments[0] === "patch") {
           arguments[0] = "create";
        } 
        Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @user10 however, it's still sending the content via the URL. I need it to work like posting a form.

Comment: I'm using backbone 1.0.0. All my POST data are sent via `Request Payload`. Nothing got patched in my url. So i'm not sure about version 0.9.10

Comment: I've upgraded to `1.0.0` and yet data is still being put into the URL.

Comment: can you set up a jsFiddle Or can you show me the screenshot of header details from network panel for that ajax call?